# Sending dynamic data from JSP to servlet

Tags: jsp, servlets

I hava a form which is populated dynamically in my JSP. Every row has a checkbox element attached to it. The user can click can select any number of rows and when he submits the form I want all the rows selected be passed to the servlet. How do i do this? This is my form element in the JSP

```
<form name="Select_Reqs" action="associate" method="post">
        <table width="500" cellpadding="1px" cellspacing="0px">
            <tr>
                <td>Req Number</td>
                <td>Business Group</td>
                <td>Hiring Manager</td>
            </tr>
            <% List <ReqDetailsBean> all_reqs = (List <ReqDetailsBean>) request.getAttribute("req_list"); 
                request.removeAttribute("req_list");
                ReqDetailsBean item = new ReqDetailsBean();
                int i=0;
                if(all_reqs.isEmpty()){
                    %>
                    <h1>List is Empty</h1>
                <%}
                while(i<all_reqs.size()){
                    item=all_reqs.get(i);
                    i++;
                    %>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <%= item.getJob_code() %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= item.getBusiness_unit() %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <%= item.getHiring_manager_name() %>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input type="checkbox" name="select_req"/>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <% }%>
        </table>
                <input type="submit" name="Submit" action="associate"/>
        </form>
```

I know I can do this in AJAX. But i dont know that technology and I have a time constraint on me. Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this in the servlet to obtain the submitted selected checkboxes:

```
String[] selected = request.getParameterValues("select_req");
```

Comment: I am sorry. Can u elaborate. I need to pass those rows which are selected by the user to the servlet from the JSP.

Comment: exactly. This line of code is placed in the servlet. and it will return an array of the selected items

Comment: I really appreciate your reply, but I am not able to make that work. It only returns an array of "on" strings. Without the "off" strings, I am not able to identify which items the user selected which he didnt.

Comment: Ok. I got it working. You need to set the value of the checkbox in the jsp. Then the values of those which are selected are passed as an array. Thanks